# Animator and Avatar

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to bring 3D model to scene. I added component "Animator", but no Avatar is applied to Animator. As far as I know, 3D model's name is supposed to be applied to "Avatar" part in Animator, and the name should be shown like the picture below. I would appreciate if you help me with this problem.

[image]

Comment: Unfold the model you will find the avatar object under it.

Comment: if it is first person character and thats have not leg body and etc. rigs you cant give that any avatar but if it have leg and other body parts rig you can build a avatar by selecting character in project ( not perfabs just the character for example "hands.fbx" ), go in inspector go to rig tab , set avatar definition and click on apply button